# Multisignature wallet with Electrum package - python

Tags: python, cryptography

I am looking for an easy way to create multisignature wallets from the command line or using a Python script. It is possible to do this from the GUI, but I cannot find any classes or examples in the documentation. I need to be able to create multisignature wallets from the command line for my project.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I would be grateful for any help.

```
class Multisig_Wallet(Deterministic_Wallet):
    # generic m of n

    def __init__(self, db, storage, *, config):
        self.wallet_type = db.get('wallet_type')
        self.m, self.n = multisig_type(self.wallet_type)
        Deterministic_Wallet.__init__(self, db, storage, config=config)
        # sanity checks
        for ks in self.get_keystores():
            if not isinstance(ks, keystore.Xpub):
                raise Exception(f"unexpected keystore type={type(ks)} in multisig")
            if bip32.xpub_type(self.keystore.xpub) != bip32.xpub_type(ks.xpub):
                raise Exception(f"multisig wallet needs to have homogeneous xpub types")

    def get_public_keys(self, address):
        return [pk.hex() for pk in self.get_public_keys_with_deriv_info(address)]

    def pubkeys_to_address(self, pubkeys):
        redeem_script = self.pubkeys_to_scriptcode(pubkeys)
        return bitcoin.redeem_script_to_address(self.txin_type, redeem_script)

    def pubkeys_to_scriptcode(self, pubkeys: Sequence[str]) -> str:
        return transaction.multisig_script(sorted(pubkeys), self.m)

    def derive_pubkeys(self, c, i):
        return [k.derive_pubkey(c, i).hex() for k in self.get_keystores()]

    def load_keystore(self):
        self.keystores = {}
        for i in range(self.n):
            name = 'x%d/'%(i+1)
            self.keystores[name] = load_keystore(self.db, name)
        self.keystore = self.keystores['x1/']
        xtype = bip32.xpub_type(self.keystore.xpub)
        self.txin_type = 'p2sh' if xtype == 'standard' else xtype

    def save_keystore(self):
        for name, k in self.keystores.items():
            self.db.put(name, k.dump())

    def get_keystore(self):
        return self.keystores.get('x1/')

    def get_keystores(self):
        return [self.keystores[i] for i in sorted(self.keystores.keys())]

    def can_have_keystore_encryption(self):
        return any([k.may_have_password() for k in self.get_keystores()])

    def _update_password_for_keystore(self, old_pw, new_pw):
        for name, keystore in self.keystores.items():
            if keystore.may_have_password():
                keystore.update_password(old_pw, new_pw)
                self.db.put(name, keystore.dump())

    def check_password(self, password):
        for name, keystore in self.keystores.items():
            if keystore.may_have_password():
                keystore.check_password(password)
        if self.has_storage_encryption():
            self.storage.check_password(password)

    def get_available_storage_encryption_version(self):
        # multisig wallets are not offered hw device encryption
        return StorageEncryptionVersion.USER_PASSWORD

    def has_seed(self):
        return self.keystore.has_seed()

    def is_watching_only(self):
        return all([k.is_watching_only() for k in self.get_keystores()])

    def get_master_public_key(self):
        return self.keystore.get_master_public_key()

    def get_master_public_keys(self):
        return [k.get_master_public_key() for k in self.get_keystores()]

    def get_fingerprint(self):
        return ''.join(sorted(self.get_master_public_keys()))
```

I tried to create instance of this class without any success.

Comment: I don't know much about wallets but have you looked at [this set of tests](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/blob/master/electrum/tests/test_wallet_vertical.py)? They seem to be creating multi-sig wallets.